# react-native - showing notification after a specific intervals of time - iOS

Tags: android, ios, notifications, react-native-ios, background-fetch

I have a scenario where I need to remind user after every specific period of time (usually 3 days) using local notification and not using internet based push-notifications.

I am using react native and have a background in Native Android specifically. I am looking for something similar to AlarmService or preferably SyncAdapter for iOS that can either be native or react-native based.

Comment: I am looking to do the same. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I made my own module for handling them, check answer below, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making my own simple module for handling scheduled local notifications... below is a snippet I am using for scheduling notification.

```
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

  //check notification permission
  [center getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
    if (settings.authorizationStatus != UNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
      // Notifications not allowed
    }else{

      // show notificaiton
      RCTLogInfo(@"Showing Notification with title: %@", title);

      //set notification content
      UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
      content.title = title;
      content.body = body;
      content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

      //add timer in ms
      NSTimeInterval timeInterval = interval;
      UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval repeats:NO];


      //set identifier with any string
      NSString *identifier = id;
      UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier content:content trigger:trigger];

      //request for scheduling notification
      [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error != nil){
          RCTLogInfo(@"Something went wrong: %@", error);
        };
      }];
    }
  }];
```

It's a stripped down version of my schedular, actual code also have support for adding image attachments but since this specific post was only about scheduling them, that's I had to drop some of the functionality.